# Jest - how to check if a function is called by another function

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, jestjs

I'm using Jest to test some Javascript. In a file, called 'function.js' I have two functions like so:

functions.js

```
const firstFunc = () => {
  const x = secondFunc()
  return x
}

const secondFunc = () => {
  return '5'
}

module.exports = {
  firstFunc,
  secondFunc
}
```

In my Jest test file I have:

```
const functions = require('./functions.js')

test('test if secondFunc is called', () => {
  const mockFunction = jest.fn()
  functions.secondFunc = mockFunction;
  functions.firstFunc()
  expect(mockFunction).toHaveBeenCalled()
})
```

I've actually tried many different variations of things like this. I'm unable to get jest.fn() to work I want it to. Overall I'm wanting to be able to see information about secondFunc, such as how many times it was called, what parameters with, etc, but I have to actually call firstFunc. Can anyone help me as I can't seem to figure this out.

Comment: This code can't be tested as it is written. When you're doing `functions.secondFunc = ...`, you're just overwriting what your module exported. Not the actual `secondFunc` function, to which there is a reference in `firstFunc` (it's a `const`, which makes it even more obvious that it's not what you are actually overwriting). Some interesting workarounds can be found [here](https://medium.com/@qjli/how-to-mock-specific-module-function-in-jest-715e39a391f4)

Comment: I feel the way you test `firstFunc` break the rule of unit testing, a unit test should only care about the expected output with given input.

Comment: @MarkoCen this example is simple, but sometimes, the fact that your function is calling another one is key in unit testing. For example, you may want to check that your function is making an POST request to some API with the correct parameters. In this case, you would mock the request library (`axios` for example) so that the request doesn't happen, but you want to check whether the correct parameters are given to it (and you don't test whether `axios` actually makes that request, since it has its own tests)

Answer (score 2):

You need to do some refactoring. Keep the same reference for `secondFunc`.
Then you can replace it with a mocked object.

`functions.js`:

```js
const firstFunc = () => {
  const x = exports.secondFunc();
  return x;
};

const secondFunc = () => {
  return '5';
};

exports.firstFunc = firstFunc;
exports.secondFunc = secondFunc;
```

unit test result:

```sh
 PASS  stackoverflow/62583841/functions.test.js (12.17s)
  ✓ test if secondFunc is called (3ms)

Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        13.779s
```

Comment: Could you include the unit the test itself as well?

Comment: @AKD Same as yours