# Jest not mocking functions properly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs

So I have a module called A with two functions:

```
function handleCreatedOrder(){
  console.log("here")
}

function acquireOrder(){
  if(condition) handleCreatedOrder
}
```

I have a test which needs to check if handleCreatedOrder is getting called. I have mocked the module by first importing the module `import * as acquireOrderWrapper from './module'`

Then in the test I am spying on the module by `let handleCreatedOrderSpy = jest.spyOn(acquireOrderWrapper, "handleCreatedOrder")`

When I try to assert `expect(handleCreatedOrder).toBeCalled()` it fails because the received number of calls does not match. I understand this is because the mocking is not proper as the console.log from `handleCreatedOrder` is called but the expect statement fails. What am I doing wrong?

My tests are currently like

```
describe("handle acquireOrder success responses", () => {
  const reactRedux = { useDispatch, useSelector }
  const useDispatchMock = jest.spyOn(reactRedux, "useDispatch")

  test("test1", async () => {
    let handleCreatedOrderSpy = jest.spyOn(acquireOrderWrapper, "handleCreatedOrder")
    await acquireOrder()
    expect(handleCreatedOrderSpy).toBeCalled()
  }
```

Comment: Could you provide the full code for your test ? Do you mock your module at the top of the file ? Or in a describe ?

Comment: I cant mock the module because  it then overrides acquireOrder()

Comment: The way you're doing it, it should only mock `handleCreatedOrder`, other functions in module should not be mocked. What I meant was, the `jest.spyOn...` line should be at the top of the file, before `describe`

Comment: I have added the test the way it is right now. I also did try out https://stackoverflow.com/a/64401168/16300815 i.e requireActual and added handleCreateOrder to a jest.fn(). It still fails.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need to do is create a spy on the handleCreatedOrder function first and then call the acquireOrder function inside your test.

The spy will then be called once you execute the acquireOrder function and your test should pass. I usually develop my frontend with angular and typescript but for reactJS it should look similiar.

```
test('test if function was called', async () => {
  jest.spyOn(component, 'handleCreatedOrder').mockImplementation();
  await acquireOrder();
  expect(component.handleCreatedOrder).toHaveBeenCalled();
}
```

you might need to add a changeDetector in your test after running the acquireOrder function. In typescript ususally i add `fixture.detectChanges` after running the function like this

```
fixture.detectChanges();
```

Also i noticed you are missing () after your function.

```
function acquireOrder(){
  if(condition) handleCreatedOrder()
}
```

Comment: I actually did have a spy for handlecreatedOrder in the question. It is a react app but I am trying to test out a function. It would not call the mocked function instead calls the original handlecreatedOrder()

Comment: mhm yes i saw your updated question. btw i noticed in your file you are using handleCreatedOrder instead of handleCreatedOrder()

Comment: I think fixture detect changes is more angular than react. Also yes I had passed the parenthesis in the actual function, so that should not be a problem

Comment: mhm honestly your test logic looks fine to me. it should work. you could try to move the test outside the describe block but idk that shouldn matter

Comment: I think that the issue is simillar to https://stackoverflow.com/a/62587700/16300815 but I am not sure how to replace the cjs exports here.